# Organize validation messages in Struts2 validation(XML)

Tags: validation, struts2, struts-validation

I am trying to do validations in struts 2 for my current project. I have to group my validation messages. For Eg: If there are 3 fields that are empty and there are 3 other fields whose format is not right, I need to get a msg like 
"The following fields are required: field1, field2, field3
The format of the following fields are invalid: field4, field5, field6"

I tried providing a param to fieldError. 
Eg:
        < s : fielderror >
                    < s : param value="%{requiredstring}"/>
   < / s : fielderror>

According to me this is like specifying "show all errors whose validator type is requiredstring". Please correct me if I am wrong.
But this will display the message "The following fields are required" each time for every field that is empty. I want it displayed only once.

Is there a way to do this cleanly in stuts2 using validation through xml? I donot want to do all the validations in a validate method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong; I have no idea why you thought that'd work, the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/fielderror.html) don't imply that's possible.

Field errors are just that--errors for a specific field. If you need to group errors by arbitrary criteria, like the validation type, you'll need to implement that yourself.

There are a number of ways to do this, including writing a custom validation interceptor, providing validators that group errors in a different way, or simply gathering the appropriate messages in an action or validation method.

You *could* gather errors based on the message content, but IMO that would be brittle. If this is a cross-application issue, you're better off doing it a different way.

All that said, by presenting error messages in an order not necessarily reflective of the form, you're pushing more cognitive overhead onto the user: I don't want to see groups of messages telling me which fields share the same error, I want to see what's wrong with each field, in the same order the fields are presented on the form, preferably near the form field itself.

Comment: I agree with you! But this requirement comes from the Business and we could not get them to agree on this. I am currently using my own validation to achieve this.